# Get GitHub branch with NodeJS with a repo logged with OAuth

Tags: node.js, github

I would get branches in a GitHub repo but with an OAuth authentication.

I use octonode (but you use another dep, no problem), so i thought get repo like that:

```
const github = require('octonode');
const client = github.client();
const repo = client.repo('https://x-oauth-basic:490b285b8f92a63abfc381aa1f7f5c40aa2f9274@github.com/my-username/my-repo.git');
```

But the result is:

```
{ [Error: Not Found]
  message: 'Not Found',
  statusCode: 404,
  headers: 
   { server: 'GitHub.com',
     date: 'Wed, 03 Oct 2018 08:37:07 GMT',
     'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
     'content-length': '77',
     connection: 'close',
     status: '404 Not Found', ... },
  body: 
   { message: 'Not Found',
     documentation_url: 'https://developer.github.com/v3' } }
```

Indeed, the goad is to get branches of the repo.

Comment: {RESOLVED} i found the solution by using the module `@octokit/rest`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the solution by using the module @octokit/rest.